# Writing ForEach Loop to database

Tags: php, mysql

This is a stupid question, but I can't seem to find an answer.

I have a foreach loop, that finds all the images on a particular link. I would like to encode all those images, and then write them to the database. If I put the sql query inside the foreach loop, then a new row is created for every images, if I put the sql query outside the foreach loop, only the first image is written. If I try to write the images and the rest of the data separately, the insert sees $newimage as null and overwrites the values. Any advice would be appreciated?

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $images) {
$newimage = json_encode($images->src);
echo $newimage;
}


$sql="INSERT INTO data (headline, images, email, date, category, area, number,   crawled, lastcrawled, description)
VALUES ('$headline', '$newimage', '$email','$date','$category','$area','$number', '$crawled', '$dt', '$description')";
```

Comment: You say what you don't want, but you never say what you're wanting -- if they're not all in their own row, do you want them all in one column? Multiple columns?

Comment: Hi, I want them all in one column. images. Here is what I want in the column:  "http:\/\/www.expatriates.com\/img\/x24206822.1.jpg.pagespeed.ic.w2EvKt56b8.jpg""http:\/\/www.expatriates.com\/img\/x24206822.2.jpg.pagespeed.ic.w2EvKt56b8.jpg""http:\/\/www.expatriates.com\/img\/x24206822.3.jpg.pagespeed.ic.JM5ilADlcu.jpg""http:\/\/www.expatriates.com\/img\/x24206822.4.jpg.pagespeed.ic.NLTh4PoNn0.jpg""http:\/\/www.expatriates.com\/img\/x24206822.5.jpg.pagespeed.ic.2aT-l3yOqk.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for, based on your comment:

```
// create an array to hold the image sources
$store_images = array();
foreach($html->find('img') as $images) {
    // add the image sources to the array
    $store_images[] = $images->src;
}

// encode the entire array of images
$json_store_images = json_encode($store_images);

// store the encoded images along with the other data
$sql="INSERT INTO data (headline, images, email, date, category, area, number,   crawled, lastcrawled, description)
VALUES ('$headline', '$json_store_images', '$email','$date','$category','$area','$number', '$crawled', '$dt', '$description')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would be helpful to you.

```
$newimages = array();
foreach($html->find('img') as $images) {
 $newimages[] = $images->src;
}

$newimage = json_encode($newimages);
```

Same sql then -

```
$sql="INSERT INTO data (headline, images, email, date, category, area, number,   
crawled, lastcrawled, description) VALUES ('$headline', '$newimage',    
$email','$date','$category','$area','$number', '$crawled', '$dt', '$description')";
```